# How to add Double Quotes to Yaml values

Tags: java, snakeyaml

```
parameter.setContext(splitName[0]); // value = dev
parameter.setRegion(splitName[1]); // value = asia
parameter.setLob(splitName[2]); // value = all
```

So this is a small piece of java code and i'm assigning some values in it as you can see. Bascially i'm writing a yaml file by reading some text file.

```
context: dev
region: asia
lob: all
```

This is Yaml file that is converted using snakeYaml Library, so my problem is i want double quotes in values eg:- "dev".

```
context: "dev"
region: "asia"
lob: "all"
```

I want the format above but I'm not able to find out how would i be able to achieve that.Please help!!

What would i have to do to add double quotes in values area in key-value pair of yaml.

Edit:

```
parameter.setContext("\""+splitName[0]+"\"");
parameter.setRegion("\""+splitName[1]+"\"");
parameter.setLob("\""+splitName[2]+"\"");
```

And if I am doing this for double quotes the output coming is like below:

```
context: '"dev"'
region: '"asia"'
lob: '"all"'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using for serialising your object before writing to the file.
I know jackson have a MINIMIZE_QUOTES which is by default enabled and quotes should be present.
You can check in document here if that is the case:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformats-text/javadoc/yaml/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLGenerator.Feature.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [the yaml spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2-old/spec.html) you can use a backslash to escape a double quote.

```
solution: "a double quote written like \" should work"
```